# (react) Listening to dropdown/select value changes triggered by changed data list propagated as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser

I am using a simple HTML select dropdown and controlling it with react (==> controlled component). Everything fine so far. The Problem is - the select options are updated via an async ajax call every few seconds and empty at the beginning. The selects data list is propagated via props.

So, the select data list changes, the selected options list changes - but no change is fired (afaik by design of react). 
I have found a working way to listen for these changes by listening to "componentDidUpdate" and firing a onChange "by hand" by reading out the value of the select as reference - but this seems very "un react-ish" (code below). Does anyone know the "react" way to do this?

Full code:

```
class Dropdown extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.dropDown = React.createRef();      
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        if (this.props.onChange) this.props.onChange(event.target.value);
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (this.props.options.length != prevProps.options.length) {
            if (this.props.onChange) this.props.onChange(this.dropDown.current.value);
        } else {
            for (let i = 0; i < this.props.options.length; i++) {
                if (this.props.options.value != prevProps.options.value) {
                    if (this.props.onChange) this.props.onChange(this.dropDown.current.value);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    render() {
        const optionList = this.props.options.map(option => <option value={option.value} key={option.value}>{option.name}</option>);
        return <select value={this.props.value} onChange={this.handleChange} ref={this.dropDown}>{optionList}</select>;
    }
}
```

props.options start as empty list. Some parent node holds this list as a state and updates it every few seconds with a ajax request.

Sandbox code: https://codesandbox.io/s/6l927kpx13

Comment: How does your parent component handle your data? Is this.props.options propagated from state?

Comment: Also what does the onChange method do? Call `this.forceUpdate()`?

Comment: You should put your code in Codesanbox, a little code above not show us enogh to help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass props to state.

```
state = {
    options: this.props.options,
}
```

render method:

```
render() {
    const optionList = this.state.options.map((option, index) => (
      <option key={index} value={option.price}>{option.price}</option>
    ));

    return (
      <select>{optionList}</select>
    );
  }
```

listener for props changes:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.options[0].price !== prevProps.options[0].price) {
      this.setState({
        options: this.props.options,
      });
    }
  }
```

Try this codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/pjky3r4z60

Comment: Came from vue - learning react this moment. If I understand this https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html right, one of the base principles of react is to lift the state up and have components as "Stateless" as possible - right? In fact this soloution is nearly identical to mine.

Answer (score 1):

React handles it's updates by looking at a component's props and state. The way you've implemented it now is mostly correct, whenever you call `setState()`, a re-render is triggered. 
However, the `onChange` event you're looking for is not whenever your options are dynamically updated, but this event gets triggered whenever your user selects a different option. This has nothing to do with React.

See the answer provided by Rizal Ibnu if you want to check for updates in a more efficient manner.

However, I would add some updates to your code, it could be shorter:

```
class Dropdown extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    // You can 'bind' this also with an arrow function
    handleChange = event => {
        if (this.props.onChange) this.props.onChange(event.target.value);
    };

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (this.props.options.length != prevProps.options.length) {
            if (this.props.onChange) this.props.onChange(this.dropDown.current.value);
        } else {
                this.props.options.forEach(() => {
                    if (this.props.options.value != prevProps.options.value) {
                        if (this.props.onChange)
                            this.props.onChange(this.dropDown.current.value);
                        return;
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <select
                value={this.props.value}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                // Consider using callback refs
                ref={dropdown => (this.dropDown = dropDown)}
            >
                // Pure preference, I like mapping a list inline
                {this.props.options.map(option => (
                    <option value={option.value} key={option.value}>
                        {option.name}
                    </option>
                ))}
            </select>
        );
    }
}
```

I would look again at the `this.props.onChange` method from your parent, I don't think it should be undefined.